# Default positioning of toolip in foundation framework

Tags: tooltip, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

In foundation version 6.5, how is the default tool tip positioning calculated?

Foundation documentation says the default position is "bottom". But even in foundation site, the example of basic tool tip isn't positioned bottom. And i'm confused about their positioning calculation for default set. kindly correct me, and explain me about tool tip default positioning.

Answer (score 0):

I see no mention of `bottom` by default but `auto`.

https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/tooltip.html

But https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop-v6.5/js/foundation.tooltip.js#L388 says `auto`.

The actual calculation is done in Positionable.setPosition, see https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop-v6.5/js/foundation.positionable.js#L121

Comment: Hi daniel, thank you for the answer. Can you please check this link [https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop-v6.5/js/foundation.positionable.js#L47], where the default positioning is set to bottom, i  believe. And initially i was using foundation 6.3, and now i have updated the new releases through npm. And after updation,  tool tips are not working properly as in the version 6.3.(with no change in html). Thanks in advance again.

Comment: This is overwritten by https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop-v6.5/js/foundation.tooltip.js#L388 afaik.